# Define variable based on loop index in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I've got very simple array consisting of two elements. Now I want to go through this array in for loop and store elements in unique variables with different name. I'm trying something like this:

```
for i in ${!array[@]};
  do
    element$i=${array[$i]}
    echo "$element{$i}" 
  done
```

But the result is error message

```
bash: element0=odm-eureka-cfg: command not found
bash: element1=github: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash just don't understand that you are declaring a variable in that line. You should just put a `declare` keyword. Also the echo command should be changed. First you should alias that dynamic variable name to some name using `declare -n`, then use that name.

```
for i in ${!array[@]};
  do
    declare element$i=${array[$i]}
    declare -n var=element$i
    echo "${var}" 
  done
```

Note: [don't use eval in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this produces just one variable var. I want to have multiple variables with unique names such as
element1=value1
element2=value2
so i can use them outside loop.

Comment: @vjancich  isn’t var updated in the loop in each iteration

Comment: Yes it is but in the end, the var contains just last value. As I mentioned before, I need to create MULTIPLE UNIQUE variables in the loop, each containing different element of array. So I just want to break array into multiple variables.

Comment: You have multiple values stored in `element$1`s. You just bind it to a var when you need to access.

Comment: I think the `$1` was a typo in the question and I just copied it. Now I changed it to `$i`

Comment: ok now I understand and it's indeed works as I want to. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use `eval` to execute the commands:

```
for i in ${!array[@]};
do
    cmd="element$i=${array[$i]}"
    eval $cmd
    cmd="echo \${element$i}"
    eval $cmd
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pointless, arrays actually meant for this. You are just copying the array itself. But for the educational purposes here you go:

```
# using printf
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
    new_var="element$i"
    printf -v $new_var "${array[$i]}"
    echo "${!new_var}" 
done

# using declare
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
    new_var="element$i"
    declare $new_var="${array[$i]}"
    echo "${!new_var}" 
done

# using read
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
    new_var="element$i"
    read $new_var <<< "${array[$i]}"
    echo "${!new_var}" 
done
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I don't fully understand. Seems to me like it creates still only one variable new_var, just chaning its value. I need to create MULTIPLE UNIQUE variables in the loop, each containing different element of array. So I just want to break array into multiple variables

Comment: @vjancich It's creating variables named with current value of `$new_var`.  This intermediate `$new_var` is needed to be able to read from those dynamically created vars like this  `echo "${!new_var}"`. Coz `echo $element$i` won't work, it'll print only `$i`.